# Thymeleaf select box for boolean values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have field at database for use that is either FALSE or TRUE
Now i have edit user function where it should have preselected value from database.

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{activated}">
    <option th:value="true" data-th-field="*{activated}">true</option>
    <option th:value="false" data-th-field="*{activated}">false</option>
</select>
```

I have tried many ways and many combinations to get it working. Then it just gets object validation failed.

Atm i know there is no preselection.
Any direction to send me to?

Comment: Checks for this discussion, probably it will help you: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-multiple-select-td4025883.html

Comment: The thymeleaf you've posted is correct (for binding a boolean true/false depending on what the user selects)... the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{activated}">
    <option th:value="1" >true</option>
    <option th:value="0" >false</option>
</select>
```

Spring will handle the converting problems.